# Windows PATH Environment Variable - How to remove all strings matching regular expression?

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

Suppose your PATH was set to:

```
c:\sw\python\3.9.0;c:\sw\python\3.9.1;c:\sw\python\3.10.0;etc
```

I'd like a clean way to remove all that match:

```
c:\sw\python\3.9.*
```

And therefore end up with a PATH of:

```
c:\sw\python\3.10.0;etc
```

My ideal solution would involve an Ansible module, but I'm fine with a pure Powershell solution, provided its very few lines and readable.

Answer (score 3):

Divide et impera works fine here. First split the path on semicolons to get a single path element, then filter out non-wanted substrings and finally re-join the results. Like so,

```
$pp = "c:\data;c:\sw\python\3.9.0;c:\sw\python\3.9.1;c:\sw\python\3.10.0;etc"
# Split the string on semicolon,
# Pick strings that do not match python\3.10
# Join the results together with semicolons as separators    
$np = ($pp.split(';') | ? {$_ -notmatch "python\\3\.[^1][^0]"} ) -join ';' 
# Output
$np
c:\data;c:\sw\python\3.10.0;etc
```